# Take the difference of 2 vectors and sum and square them

Tags: matrix, matlab

I have 2 vectors of size 1x90.

I have to do the operator

```
diff=sum((V_new-V).^2);
```

But every time i do it i get the error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logical.
```

How can i fix this problem and prevent it from occurring again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339173/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals)

Comment: I think the reason is that you use `sum` as a variable before `diff=sum((V_new-V).^2);`.

Comment: @tqjustc - have you bothered to look at other answers here before commenting?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 3):

make sure you did not step over the `sum` function:

1. type

   ```
   >> dbstop if error
   ```
2. run the code, it should stop in debugger when error occurred.
3. check what `sum` is:

   ```
   >> which sum
   ```

   should return that `sum` is a build-in function, but if you accidentally created a variable with that name, it will tell you that `sum` is a variable.

**DO NOT USE BUILT-IN FUNCTIONS' NAMES AS VARIABLES**

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "step over" the sum function please?

Comment: A more apt title should be: Take the difference of every element of the 2 vectors square them and then sum all those values together.

Comment: @ECE - is it possible you created a variable with the name `sum`?

Comment: "DO NOT USE BUILT-IN FUNCTIONS' NAMES AS VARIABLES": same goes for **diff**, which is a built-in function.

Comment: In fact, you could have used the built-in function **diff** to calculate the difference between the vectors: diff(V_new, V)

Comment: I did have a variable by the name sum, and diff and i changed both. Here is the new command:         difference_value=sum((V_new-V).^2);

Comment: run `clear sum` before you run your code. Make sure (in debug) that `sum` points to the built-in function

Comment: thank you! i have to do clear sum and clear diff. I appreciate it Shai!